# Facebook Graph Api - writing new lines in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting an event using Facebook Graph API and PHP using the following code:

```
$id = '160307307413666';
$FBpage = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'. $id);
$FBdata = json_decode($FBpage);
echo $FBdata->description;
```

The problem is when using json_decode($FBpage); i loose all the /n (new line) that i would like to render.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: where are rendering the data ? on browser

Comment: You don't lose them. Please read more about HTML. Whitespaces (like a newline, space, tab) are reduced to one space. If you need to render a linebreak, you need a `<br>` tag or you need to use `<pre>` which will display all the whitespaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i assume you're looking for

```
echo '<pre>';
echo $FBdata->description;
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

use this function 
`nl2br`
which will convert all new lines `\n` to `<br/>` tag